Why JMS Serializer prefixes UPPERCASE properties with an underscore?
Is it normal for JMS Serializer to transform an object property called LDAP (note the capital letters) into _ldap (note the underscore)?
Array before:

Array after serialization:

If this property is NOT fully uppercased, then the "normal" behavior is applied.
Should I try to prevent it with an Identical Property Naming Strategy?

Does it not unserialize correctly?
